# YouTube Data API Client Library for .NET - get videos from list of channels

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, youtube, youtube-api

is it possible to get e.g 10 the newest videos from list of channels ?
I use ASP.NET MVC 5.

Here's my flow:
1. Get 10 newest videos for 5 channels
2. Show result on the page

If you need some more information, just let me know.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can use This code bt javascript :

```
// Get Uploads Playlist
$.get(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels",{
    part : 'contentDetails', 
    forUsername : 'USER_CHANNEL_NAME',
    key: 'YOUR_API_KEY'},
    function(data) {
       $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
           pid = item.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
           getVids(pid);
       });
   }
 );

 //Get Videos
 function getVids(pid){
     $.get(
         "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems",{
         part : 'snippet', 
         maxResults : 20,
         playlistId : pid,
         key: 'YOUR_API_KEY'},
         function(data) {
             var results;
             $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
                 results = '<li>'+ item.snippet.title +'</li>';
                 $('#results').append(results);
             });
         }
     );
 }
```

Or you can watch [YouTube video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RjUlmco7v2M) through the v3 API calls .

Or you can read the [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) for more information.